# Работа скрипта в подгружаемом файле с помощью ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Доброго времени суток.
Проблема такая: при подгрузке с помощью ajax html файла и добавления его содержимого в разметку основного, скрипт который содержится в этом подгружаемом файле не работает. 
Файлы:

- index.html
- main.css
- main.js
- cartform.html
- cartform.js
- successfully.html

.

В main.js прописан скрип для подгрузки файла cartform.html, в котором подключается файл cartform.js. В cartform.js прописан скрип для пордгрузки файла successfully.html.

Ajax в main.js и cartform.js примерно одинаковый:

```js
function successfully() {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if ( xhr.readyState !== XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
      return;
    }
    document.getElementsByClassName('hamburger')[0].innerHTML += xhr.response;
  }
  xhr.open( 'GET', 'successfully.html');
  xhr.send();
};
```

Полный код тут: https://jodest.github.io/Karev_Dmitriy_JS2/3/LuckyBurger/
https://github.com/Jodest/jodest.github.io/tree/master/Karev_Dmitriy_JS2/3/LuckyBurger

Можно как то решить проблему без применения jquery?
Или как подключить скрипт, в котором есть слушатель события, который реагирует на элемент, которого еще нету на страницы?

P.s. строго не судите, я новичок в js(

Comment: не делайте так. Подключайте сразу все скрипты. Не надо грузить их по ajax

Comment: Как подключить скрипт, в котором есть слушатель события, который реагирует на элемент, которого еще нету на страницы?

Comment: Отредакируйте основной вопрос, добавив туда этот. Тогда я смогу дать вам нормальный ответ по теме

Comment: В топик добавил вопрос, или в название топика надо?

Comment: Дайте минут 5-10

Comment: Чтобы слушалось событие только на при существующем элементе, делаем проверку if(document.getelementbyid(element), тогда добавляем слушатель. И скрипт не ломается.

Comment: @NeedHate Так в комменте написано, что элемента ещё не существует

Answer (score 1):

Вариант отложенного запуска скрипта:

```js
function emulate_ajax() {
  var c = document.getElementById('container');
  c.innerHTML = "<p class='text'>123</p>";
  c.dispatchEvent(new Event('updated'));
};

document.getElementById('container').addEventListener('updated', function() {
  console.log(document.querySelector('p.text'));
});

emulate_ajax();
```

```html
<div id='container'></div>
```

Но это костыль все-таки. Красивый вариант - модули и webpack, но пугать ими Вас явно рано

Comment: Спасибо! Буду пробовать)
Webpack у меня наверно через месяц в обучении будет вместе с react'ом. А для себя уже давно хотел webpack попробовать как замена gulp для сборки проектов.